# Compile Opus for Android with NDK 20

Tags: android, android-ndk, opus

I'm compiling opus to use it on Android. Tried my best to compose the right CMakeLists file with the right flags and sources. This is how it looks like now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_compile_options(-DOPUS_BUILD -DUSE_ALLOCA -DFIXED_POINT -D__OPTIMIZE__)

include_directories(opus/include
                    opus/src
                    opus/silk
                    opus/silk/fixed
                    opus/silk/arm
                    opus/celt
                    opus/celt/arm)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             jnopus

    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED

    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
    opus/src/analysis.c
    opus/src/mapping_matrix.c
    opus/src/mlp.c
    opus/src/mlp_data.c
    opus/src/opus.c
    opus/src/opus_compare.c
    opus/src/opus_decoder.c
    opus/src/opus_encoder.c
    opus/src/opus_multistream.c
    opus/src/opus_multistream_decoder.c
    opus/src/opus_multistream_encoder.c
    opus/src/opus_projection_decoder.c
    opus/src/opus_projection_encoder.c
    opus/src/repacketizer.c

    opus/silk/A2NLSF.c
    opus/silk/ana_filt_bank_1.c
    opus/silk/biquad_alt.c
    opus/silk/bwexpander.c
    opus/silk/bwexpander_32.c
    opus/silk/check_control_input.c
    opus/silk/CNG.c
    opus/silk/code_signs.c
    opus/silk/control_audio_bandwidth.c
    opus/silk/control_codec.c
    opus/silk/control_SNR.c
    opus/silk/debug.c
    opus/silk/dec_API.c
    opus/silk/decode_core.c
    opus/silk/decode_frame.c
    opus/silk/decode_indices.c
    opus/silk/decode_parameters.c
    opus/silk/decode_pitch.c
    opus/silk/decode_pulses.c
    opus/silk/decoder_set_fs.c
    opus/silk/enc_API.c
    opus/silk/encode_indices.c
    opus/silk/encode_pulses.c
    opus/silk/gain_quant.c
    opus/silk/HP_variable_cutoff.c
    opus/silk/init_decoder.c
    opus/silk/init_encoder.c
    opus/silk/inner_prod_aligned.c
    opus/silk/interpolate.c
    opus/silk/lin2log.c
    opus/silk/log2lin.c
    opus/silk/LP_variable_cutoff.c
    opus/silk/LPC_analysis_filter.c
    opus/silk/LPC_fit.c
    opus/silk/LPC_inv_pred_gain.c
    opus/silk/NLSF2A.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_decode.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_del_dec_quant.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_encode.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_stabilize.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_unpack.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_VQ.c
    opus/silk/NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c
    opus/silk/NSQ.c
    opus/silk/NSQ_del_dec.c
    opus/silk/pitch_est_tables.c
    opus/silk/PLC.c
    opus/silk/process_NLSFs.c
    opus/silk/quant_LTP_gains.c
    opus/silk/resampler.c
    opus/silk/resampler_down2.c
    opus/silk/resampler_down2_3.c
    opus/silk/resampler_private_AR2.c
    opus/silk/resampler_private_down_FIR.c
    opus/silk/resampler_private_IIR_FIR.c
    opus/silk/resampler_private_up2_HQ.c
    opus/silk/resampler_rom.c
    opus/silk/shell_coder.c
    opus/silk/sigm_Q15.c
    opus/silk/sort.c
    opus/silk/stereo_decode_pred.c
    opus/silk/stereo_encode_pred.c
    opus/silk/stereo_find_predictor.c
    opus/silk/stereo_LR_to_MS.c
    opus/silk/stereo_MS_to_LR.c
    opus/silk/stereo_quant_pred.c
    opus/silk/sum_sqr_shift.c
    opus/silk/table_LSF_cos.c
    opus/silk/tables_gain.c
    opus/silk/tables_LTP.c
    opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.c
    opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_WB.c
    opus/silk/tables_other.c
    opus/silk/tables_pitch_lag.c
    opus/silk/tables_pulses_per_block.c
    opus/silk/VAD.c
    opus/silk/VQ_WMat_EC.c

    opus/silk/fixed/apply_sine_window_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/corrMatrix_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/encode_frame_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/find_LPC_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/find_LTP_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/find_pitch_lags_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/find_pred_coefs_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/k2a_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/k2a_Q16_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/noise_shape_analysis_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/process_gains_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/regularize_correlations_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy16_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/schur_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/schur64_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/vector_ops_FIX.c
    opus/silk/fixed/warped_autocorrelation_FIX.c

    opus/silk/arm/arm_silk_map.c
    opus/silk/arm/biquad_alt_neon_intr.c
    opus/silk/arm/LPC_inv_pred_gain_neon_intr.c
    opus/silk/arm/NSQ_del_dec_neon_intr.c
    opus/silk/arm/NSQ_neon.c

    opus/celt/bands.c
    opus/celt/celt.c
    opus/celt/celt_decoder.c
    opus/celt/celt_encoder.c
    opus/celt/celt_lpc.c
    opus/celt/cwrs.c
    opus/celt/entcode.c
    opus/celt/entdec.c
    opus/celt/entenc.c
    opus/celt/kiss_fft.c
    opus/celt/laplace.c
    opus/celt/mathops.c
    opus/celt/mdct.c
    opus/celt/modes.c
    opus/celt/pitch.c
    opus/celt/quant_bands.c
    opus/celt/rate.c
    opus/celt/vq.c
    opus/celt/arm/arm_celt_map.c
    opus/celt/arm/armcpu.c
    opus/celt/arm/celt_mdct_ne10.c
    opus/celt/arm/celt_neon_intr.c
    opus/celt/arm/pitch_neon_intr.c

    org_jitsi_impl_neomedia_codec_audio_opus_Opus.c)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       jnopus)
```

So far its working but I'm not sure if there are some mistakes or something missing ... it feels a bit odd.

I've also managed to compile the "fixed point" version only, for the "float" version its not working. If someone has an idea how to do that (apart from adding float sources) ...

Comment: how did you finish the project ?

Comment: Haven't pursuit it further, it was a side feature and I had to move to the next project.